# I am getting 500 error when enabling pretty permalinks

Tags: permalinks

I have a wordpress setup on digital ocean. I am facing a wierd issue that when I am enabling the pretty permalinks for the website the inner pages show 500 error. my .htaccess file has permission of 755.

Comment: You need to check what could be the exact cause of the error, check the debug logs. Also, try to deactivate other plugins and change the theme. See if the error would go away. If you already know the exact error, find a solution for it.

Comment: a HTTP 500 is a super generic server error, it means "something went wrong". To figure out what the problem is you have to look at the PHP error log on your server to find the _actual_ error message. You may need to turn error logging on if it is disabled. The HTAccess permissions are highly unlikely to be a factor here. Until you do this, you have no idea what happened